# AS3 FLVPLaybackCaptioning Component Displaying Images?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3, flvplayback

I am using the FLVPlaybackCaptioning Component to display captions for a video. We've built a player that uses a FLV file hosted locally or streamed from the server to show captions for a video, a slide title, and slide text. The example is up here:

http://www.brainline.org/multimedia/webreadyplayer

I want to display images using the FLVPlaybackCaptioning component. It pulls from an XML file into a dynamic textField with Multiline selected and HTML enabled. So it should allow me to display images into the text field. However it will not allow me to show images using html code. I'm using DXFP format for the XML caption file and the line I'm looking at is:

```
<p begin="00:00:36.00"><img src="http://www.brainline.org/multimedia/slide1.jpg"/></p>
```

This will not allow the image to load in. I've tried specifying the image locally on my machine, on another domain and just about everything to get it to show up. Any ideas how I can use the FLVPlaybackCaptioning Component to display images?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read about it, it seems to only accept xml data. If you are able to determine whre you are at in the video as it plays you might be able to make a listener to check that then load it in a placeholder.

One other trick I have used in the past is to load images into a multiline text symbol by using a simple image html tag as the content of the text. If you could dynamically populate the src= part of that tag then it might work but the FLVPlaybackCaptioning doesn't seem to support images directly.

You could make your xml consist of `<img src="captionimage.gif">` and load that xml into the text and see if that works.